# How can we obtain the name of the branch from which the pull request triggering a travis build originated, when in the travis environment?

Tags: git, travis-ci

Currently, for builds being triggered by PRs we can obtain the target branch of the pull request using the environment variable, TRAVIS_BRANCH.
Similarly, is there any way to obtain and use the branch from which the PR originates?

Background: I am running a script on travis (post a successful build) which will require cloning both the target branch and the branch requesting the merge on the travis machine itself in order to run some tests on them using the [Rperform](https://github.com/da-ta-vinci21/Rperform) package.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documuntation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Default-Environment-Variables), it is: `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH`